# Chrome Developer Tools: Bug while live edit

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I'm experiencing an odd behaviour with Chrome Developer Tools which started after I believe after last update (I'm using Version 33.0.1750.117 m)

While doing a live edit on a stylesheet, if the background is white, then I can edit fine, but if the background change colors and a yellow warning sign appears on the css tab, then as I edit, the characters disappear, or the cursor moves to the middle of the word I'm typing. It does several times. Almost 3-4 times per word. It's a nightmare to use it now.

Any ideas on how to fix that? I've tried changing some of the settings but no success. Thanks!

Comment: 10+1s to this questions, this is a huge issue for me as well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a fix that stops the stuttering, but you also lose autocomplete.

This is better than having the stutter in my opinion.

1. Click the Settings Icon (the gear) in chrome devtools
2. Go to the Sources subheading

<s>3. Uncheck **autocompletion**</s>

**EDIT**

It turns out autocompletion was a red herring.

To actually fix this bug, uncheck **Auto-reload generated CSS**

Comment: Thank you! Yes I had actually unchecked that while trying different settings and it seems to be working. It has been a major waste of time.

Comment: Well, yeah it was short lived. 

Also I changed computers, now running Windows 8. I have **Auto-reload generated CSS** unchecked and it is still not fixed. :/

Comment: This problem has just started for me - in Chrome Version 50.0.2661.86 (64-bit)